# Get light transparent text field in css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a login page for my website and I want to have my two text fields lightly transparent and the placeholder to be white. Here is a picture of what I mean
[image]

I've been looking all over and cannot find something similar to that design of the text field. I believe it has something to do with this code

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

but I am not sure. If someone has any idea on how this person achieved this please help out. Also this isn't a website so i couldn't use inspect element, this is a img i found on google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set my input boxes semi-transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266640/set-my-input-boxes-semi-transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.text-field {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='text-field' placeholder='Your full name' />
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #250aba;
}

.field {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  border: none;
  padding: 7px 22px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.go {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 255, 0.94);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px 27px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 35%;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    <input type="password" class="field" name="psw" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    <button class="go">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This should look nice. The background is indigo, and the text fields, because of their alpha (the "a" in `rgba`) are transparent black. Notice how the fields appear to be a light purple.

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

input {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" First name"><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last name">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```